# GridItem and GridContainer

Tags: java, object-oriented

This library provides methods for storing items into an inventory. the container is based on a grid as well as the items going into that container.

[image]

can you please review the code in any way?

```
public interface GridContainer {
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getContainer();
    public Collection<GridShape> getContent();
    public boolean fitsInside(GridShape container, GeoPoint location);
    public void add(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location);
    public GridShape remove(GeoPoint location);
}
```

```
public interface GridShape {
    public boolean fitsInside(GridContainer container, GeoPoint pointer);
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getShape();
    public GeoPoint getPointer();
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getRelativeShape(GeoPoint point);
}
```

so far we have an implementation for rectangle shaped containers and items

```
public class RectangleContainer implements GridContainer {

    private final List<GeoPoint> shape;
    private final Map<GeoPoint, GridShape> content;

    public RectangleContainer(int width, int height){
        shape = Collections.unmodifiableList(RectangleUtility.createShape(width, height));
        content = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getContainer() {
        return shape;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GridShape> getContent() {
        return content.values();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fitsInside(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) {
        Collection<GeoPoint>relativeShape = shape.getRelativeShape(location);
        boolean hasIntersections = hasIntersection(relativeShape);
        boolean isInBounds = isInBounds(relativeShape);
        return !hasIntersections && isInBounds;
    }

    private boolean isInBounds(Collection<GeoPoint>relativeShape) {
        for (GeoPoint point: relativeShape){
            if (!shape.contains(point)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean hasIntersection(Collection<GeoPoint>relativeShape) {
        for (Map.Entry<GeoPoint, GridShape> entry: content.entrySet()){
            for (GeoPoint pointOfContent: entry.getValue().getRelativeShape(entry.getKey())){
                if (relativeShape.contains(pointOfContent)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) {
        content.put(location, shape);
    }

    @Override
    public GridShape remove(GeoPoint location) {
        return content.remove(location);
    }
}
```

```
public class RectangleItem<I> implements GridShape, ItemHolder<I> {

    private final List<GeoPoint> shape;
    private I item;

    public RectangleItem(int width, int height){
        shape = Collections.unmodifiableList(RectangleUtility.createShape(width, height));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fitsInside(GridContainer container, GeoPoint pointer) {
        return container.fitsInside(this, pointer);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    @Override
    public GeoPoint getPointer() {
        return shape.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GeoPoint> getRelativeShape(GeoPoint point) {
        return shape.stream().map(p -> new GeoPoint(p.getX()+point.getX(), p.getY() + point.getY())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public I getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public void setItem(I item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Note: i've skipped the `test classes` and the `RectangleUtility` class, the **geoLib project**  and the `ItemHolder` since they are not scope of the review. If they are required please feel free to add a comment asking for them, then i'll add them. (i think this question is already bloated, that's the reason for deciding so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General

### Task

In my opinion you lost the focus of your task description:

> [...]storing **items** into an **inventory**. The container is based on a grid as well as the items going into that container.

The word `container` can easily be replaced by `inventory`:

> [...] storing **items** into an **inventory**. The **inventory** is based on a **grid** as well as the **items** going into that **inventory**.

The goal is to store items in an `Inventory`/`Container` but currently it stores `Shapes` instead of `Items`:

> ```java
> public class RectangleContainer implements GridContainer {
>
>   /* ... */
>   private final Map<GeoPoint, GridShape> content;
>
>   /* ... */
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean fitsInside(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) { /* ... */ }
>
>   /* ... */
>
>   @Override
>   public void add(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) { /* ... */ }
>
>
> }
> ```

### What is an Item

#### What an Item currently is

> ```java
> public class RectangleItem<I> implements GridShape, ItemHolder<I> { /* ... */}
> ```

To make it simpler to discuss:

> ```java
> public class Item<I> implements Shape, ItemHolder<I> { /* ... */}
> ```

Is `Item` an `Item`? When I see only the class name I would say yes, but after looking on the signature I would say: "It could be". 
From the signature it is an item that is a shape that holds an item.
Is it an item that holds an other item?

#### What an Item should be

A `Item` is something that **has a** `Shape`.

> ```java
> public class Item<I> {
>
>     private I value;
>     private Shape shape;
>
>     public Item(I value, Shape shape) { /* ... */ }
>
> }
> ```

and an `ìtem` should be packed into an inventory/container:

```java
public class RectangleContainer implements GridContainer {
    /* ... */
    @Override    public void add(Item item, GeoPoint location) {/* ... */}
}
```

## Code Smell

### Feature Envy

Inside `RectangleContainer#fitsInside(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location)` is the following line:

```java
Collection<GeoPoint> relativeShape = shape.getRelativeShape(location);
```

The `relativeShape` gets passed into `hasIntersection` and `isInBounds` of `RectangleContainer`:

> ```java
> @Override
> public boolean fitsInside(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) {
>   Collection<GeoPoint> relativeShape = shape.getRelativeShape(location);
>   boolean hasIntersections = hasIntersection(relativeShape);
>   boolean isInBounds = isInBounds(relativeShape);
>   return !hasIntersections && isInBounds;
> }
> ```

Because `RectangleContainer` works with the internals of `shape` (`relativeShape`) it is a [feature envy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy).

You could return a custom object `PositionedItem` that has the methods `intersectsNotInside(inventory)` and `isInBoundOf(inventory)`:

```java
@Override
public boolean fitsInside(Item item, GeoPoint location) {
   PositionedItem positionedItem = shape.at(location);
   return !positionedItem.intersectsNotInside(this) && positionedItem.isInBoundOf(this);
}
```

The benefit will be that you will not have duplicate logic for `hasIntersections` and `isInBounds` in the different subtypes of `GridContainer`.

## Redundant Public

In both interfaces `GridContainer` and `GridShape` you have used the key word `public`. Per default are fields in an interface are `public`.

Also valid java:

```java
public interface GridShape {
    boolean fitsInside(GridContainer container, GeoPoint pointer);
    Collection<GeoPoint> getShape();
    GeoPoint getPointer();
    Collection<GeoPoint> getRelativeShape(GeoPoint point);
}
```

## Everything is addable

> ```java
> @Override
> public void add(GridShape shape, GeoPoint location) {
>    content.put(location, shape);
> }
> ```

I could add a `shape`, that is 1000 times bigger as a `RectangleContainer`..

The adding of a `shape` should be checked so that it is not possible to at wrong shapes

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time on this review! I'm so glad to learn so many things from you!